# Azure Active Directory C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have an application with my own user system that I built for my company.  We have azure active directory and I can not figure out how to use it for the life of me.

I simply want to send a username and password and find out if they are the user they say they are according to AD.

Where do I start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication with Azure Active Directory - how to accept user credentials programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794759/authentication-with-azure-active-directory-how-to-accept-user-credentials-prog)

Comment: You should not collect user credentials in your app, this approach is highly recommend *against*. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39250380/325697) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28597758/325697) answers for some more details on why you should *not* do this, and instead, implement a modern sign-in flow (e.g. [using the MSAL library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet)). It'll be much easier, more durable, less error-prone, and most importantly&mdash;less of a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides code samples such as:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/Graph-Security-API-Auth-Sample

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you want to authenticate to Azure AD using a username & password.

Here is a [sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/) that demonstrate a .Net console application calling a web API that is secured using Azure AD. the application does not require user interaction through a Web browser:

1.The .Net application uses the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) to obtain a JWT access token through the OAuth 2.0 protocol.

2.The access token is sent to the web API to authenticate the user.